# Locating Element using XPath and CSS

Tags: css, xpath, selenium

How will you locate the element using its “Click Payment History” text using XPATH & CSS?

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>My Account</title>
    </head>

    <body> 
        <table> 
            <tr><td>John</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Shield</td></tr> 
        </table> 

        <div>Click Payment History</div> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: At the server or at the client?  What language?  Your question is lacking details and you may find it closed.

Comment: The code is : <html> 
    <head>
        <title>My Account</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td>John</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Shield</td></tr>
        </table>
        <div>Click Payment History</div>
    </body>
    
</html>

Answer (score 1):

In CSS:

```
div
```

In xpath:

```
//div
```

Not maintainable but they'll work for your example.

Answer (score 0):

A way to find xpath is [Firepath](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/firepath/) an extension of Firebug.

Comment: not exactly. Firepath allows you to enter found xpath, css selector and locate appropriate web element on web page. But finding can be performed in HTML tab of firebug as well.